# How to get language culture from given language name?

Tags: c#, language-translation, google-translation-api

I take source and target languages from the user as input and I want to generate culture of these inputs as following using .Net libraries;

For example, the user chooses 'English' and 'Turkish' from two combo boxes. Then I'd like to generate 'En' from 'English' and 'Tr' from Turkish. I'd like to make this happen for all possible languages, what's the correct way to do this?

I'll use these cultures in my request to translate a text, instead of this;

```
string url = String.Format("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={0}&tl={1}&dt=t&q={2}",
       "En", "Tr", Uri.EscapeUriString(input));
```

I want to use this;

```
string url = String.Format("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={0}&tl={1}&dt=t&q={2}",
       sourceLanguage, targetLanguage, Uri.EscapeUriString(input));
```

I do not want to use a dictionary because then I'll need to put all the information manually for each language, I'd like to do it with CultureInfo class but I haven't figure it out how to do.

Comment: And what is your actual problem? Knowing the valid language ids?

Comment: You could associate this information to the language name from the start. Using, e.g., a `Dictionary<string, string>` that contains the pairs: `English, en-GB`, `Turkish, tr-TR` and so on. You got those names into your ComboBoxes somehow.

Comment: What I want to do is basically converting 'English' to 'En', 'Turkish' to 'Tr' etc. using .Net libraries.

Comment: I do not want to use a dictionary because then I'll need to put all the information manually for each language, I'd like to do it with CultureInfo class but I haven't figure it out how to do

Comment: All right, but, how did you add those names to the ComboBoxes? You should have a collection of strings for that, some kind of source. Note that, e.g., `English` is quite *vague*. You have ~10 sub-languages that use that name. Anyways, you could get the first Culture where the `DisplayName.StartsWith("English")` and read its `TwoLettersISOLanguageName` property.

Comment: I used an enum called 'Languages' which contains all the languages that I need to translate, then I set this enum as my combobox's item source. 
User selects the target and source languages from boxes, then I need to get the language culture as mentioned above.

Comment: Why don't you use a Dictionary instead of an Enum? You can use it as the source of data of those ComboBoxes anyway and you don't have to do anything more when you have done it.

Comment: Because I only need to specify languages, then I need a method to convert into language culture from given string, it will solve my problem efficiently.

Comment: Well, if you do something like this: `var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures).FirstOrDefault(c => c.DisplayName.StartsWith("English"))?.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;`, is it good enough?

Comment: That's perfect!! Thanks a lot. @Jimi

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Globalization`.

Add using statement: `using System.Globalization;`

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

foreach (CultureInfo ci in cultures)
{
    string output = String.Format("Name: {0} DisplayName: {1} 2-Letter Name: {2} 3-Letter Name: {3}", ci.Name, ci.DisplayName, ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, ci.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(output);
}
```

**Note**: The data you want is in property `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`.